# How do i import ast module in google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, abstract-syntax-tree

Am having a challenge importing ast (Abstract Syntax Tree) module in my appengine app. On my local development machine, everything is working fine, but after i deployed the app to the production appengine i get the following error;

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named ast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.365758902437943607/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ast
```

Does google appengine support ast module?

Gath

Comment: `ast` was introduced in Python 2.6 (`_ast` in Python 2.5). Check your Python version to see if it's at least 2.6

Comment: On my dev machine am using 2.6 & 2.7

Comment: Your local machine doesn't matter in this case. You must check your GAE Python version. As I'm almost certain it will be 2.5, you might as well take a look at [this migration guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27)

Comment: @DJV - you right, was running 2.5, migrating my app now, thanks.

Comment: Would you mind answering the question so i can accept the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module was introduced in Python 2.6 (it's lower level counterpart `_ast` in Python 2.5. Despite having Python 2.6+ on your dev machine, it doesn't matter for your GAE production environment. Take a look at [this migration guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27) in order to migrate your GAE environment from Python 2.5 to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of python on your deployment host

```
python -V
```

ISTR ast is not in python 2.5

Comment: on my local dev server am using 2.6 & 2.7

Comment: it's irrelevant what you are using on your local dev server.

Comment: @Paul C - you right, was running 2.5 on production migrating my app now to 2.7, thanks.